# How can I redirect to another page if a field has been entered 12345?

Tags: javascript

There is a field `<input>` with the id `"page"`, and I got it with `document.getElementById('page')`. I now try to read the value with `getValue()`, but nothing happens - what I am doing wrong?

The idea here is the:

Into the input field I entered `12345678910` and then determine that the first five digits are 12345 so the page 12345.html is opened. If I enter 1234581530 it will also open 12345.html. So you need only read the first five digits and then open the file you want, I hope understood my idea.

Sorry for the question, but I am still learning, I would be very grateful if you would give me some examples.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the best way of learning is trying

Comment: 12345 is the only starting input on which you want to redirect page?,
or any first 5 characters will be your page name?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `getValue` method. You should read `value` property:

```
var page = document.getElementById('page').value.substr(0, 5);
location.href = page + '.html';
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q8bQc/

Comment: because of `onkeyup` one can't insert `12345678910`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

To get the value (there is no `getValue`, just `value`)

```
var str = document.getElementById('page').value;
```

To cut it to 5 chars -

```
str = str.substring(0, 5); // or substr(0, 5)
```

To open a different link -

```
location.href = str + '.html';
```

**Or as a single line -**

```
location.href = document.getElementById('page').value.substring(0, 5) + '.html';
```

Comment: what am I doing wrong in my example?
`<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var value = document.getElementById('page').value;
value = value.substring(0, 5);

window.open(value + '.html','_self') 
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="page" id="page">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub string to get the first 5 characters:

```
var str = value = document.getElementById('page').value; // The input
var res = str.substring(0,5); // The first 5 characters
```

And then some if statement to determine if they equal 12345

```
if(res == "12345") {

};
```

Now all you need to do is open the link which can be done like:

```
window.open("/12345.html","_self")
```

Which will open the link in the same window

All together:

```
var str = value = document.getElementById('page').value; // The input
var res = str.substring(0,5); // The first 5 characters
if(res == "12345") {
    window.open("/12345.html","_self")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First set the element value then cut it and open the link

```
var value = document.getElementById('page').value;
value = value.substring(0, 5);

window.open(value + '.html') //To Open in a new tab
window.open(value + '.html','_self') //To Open in the same tab
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/52vtQ/

$(function () {

```
var a;
$("#sub").click(function () {
    a = $('#page').val();
    alert(a);
});
```

});

maybe this will help you out with your problem